# Why do doctrine namespaces with App\Entity instead of App\Model in Symfony framework not work? (See error message below)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am newbie to Symfony, so I was following a YouTube Tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4LotIQWVfew&list=PL4zTp90ptQJNjL5xzhn0fgVgd0k1YkpL-&index=7&ab_channel=thomasd_codes - Episode 7) and was stuck from 8:00 min on. I did as shown there:
I changed the folder's name "Model" to "Entity", also the namespaces given in the Subscriptions.php and the SubscriptionsController.php file. The doctrine.yaml file is set up correctly as well with the prefix "App\Entity" - everything as shown in the video. But the symfony framework alsways throws an exeption as following:

[Screenshot of the Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbduw.png)

The "use" statement is set as well.

I am using PHP version 7.1 as well as Symfony 4.4.18 (mended statement about the version) running on IIS 10 - maybe it has something to do with this?

I already did researches on this, but I haven't found any solutions to this issue so far.
Would be great if somebody could help me out there! Thanks a lot in advance!

SubscriptionsController.php:

```
<?php 
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Subscription;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response; 

class SubscriptionsController extends AbstractController
{
    public function list(): Response
    {
        $response = new Response(); 

        $dataArray = [

            'success' => true,
            'subscriptions' => $this->generateSubscriptions(),

        ]; 

        return $this->json($dataArray);

    }

    protected function generateSubscriptions(): array
    {
        $returnArray = [];

        $returnArray[] = (new Subscription)
            ->setStartDate(new \DateTime()) 
            ->setName("Netflix"); 

            $returnArray[] = (new Subscription)
            ->setStartDate(new \DateTime("2021-11-26")) 
            ->setName("Amazon-Prime"); 

            $returnArray[] = (new Subscription)
            ->setStartDate(new \DateTime()) 
            ->setName("ADAC"); 

        return $returnArray; 
        
    }

}
```

And Subscriptions.php:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Entity; 

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Subscription implements \JsonSerializable
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id 
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue 
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer") 
     */

    protected $id; 

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255) 
     */
    
    protected $name; 

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */

    protected $startDate;

    public function jsonSerialize() 
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->name,
            'startDate' => $this->startDate,
        ];
    }

    public function getName(): string 
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self 
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getStartDate(): \DateTime 
    {
        return $this->startDate;
    }

    public function setStartDate(\DateTime $startDate): self 
    {
        $this->startDate = $startDate;

        return $this;
    } 

}
```

composer.json:

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.1.3",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "composer/package-versions-deprecated": "1.11.99.1",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.2",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^2.2",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.7",
        "symfony/console": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "4.4.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "4.4.*"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tutorial seems to use Symfony 5 and you Symfony v4.22.0. Said that, have you cleared the cache?

Comment: Please share more details. Where is that error thrown? Also, PHP 7.1 is pretty old, while Symfonv 4.22 doesn't even exist

Comment: This has nothing to do with Doctrine.  You just have an issue with PHP's autoloader.  Definitely try clearing the cache as previously suggested.  If that does not help then update your question with the contents of the psr-4 section of composer.json.  The 4.22.0 is actually the version number of the Symfony executable used to create projects.  Run 'bin/console --version' to clarify the actual Symfony version you are using.

Comment: Finally, learning from random youtube tutorials might not be the best use of your time. I would suggest following the Symfony docs.  Or if you really want videos then use the Symfony video casts at least until you understand the basics.

Comment: Ok Cerad, I took all the steps you said I should take, but unfortunately without success. I've updated the Symfony version (which is 4.4.18) in the question section and added the whole composer.json file. 

What else can I try? 

P.S. I am running the project with an IIS 10 - so I cleared both the inbuilt server cache of Symfony and the cache of the IIS server, but both of them threw the Symfony error message (See screenshot in the question section above).

Comment: you still have your old codebase. I think Cerad suggested starting with an official tutorial, thus having a pristine codebase. That being said, if your file containing App\Entity\Subscription really is called `Subscriptions.php`, then renaming it to `Subscription.php` might help. Also, if it really is an entity, I believe the `@ORM\Entity` annotation is missing, but not quite certain (and it doesn't matter concerning your error message)

Comment: Your file name and yout class name must be same. You file is `Subscriptions.php` and your class `Subscription` : change your file name.

Comment: so following YouTube is a great way to learn. I have posted a few myself. One thing to note if you are learning Symfony I would start with version 5 and not version 4. There are changes from the two versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comments, Jakumi and Hamham!

Renaming the file to "Subscription.php" finally solved the problem!